# I have 2 __pycache__ folders I want to remove

Tags: directory, removing

I've tried running the `find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf` command but it says access denied. I can't find any better help. I'm a complete computer idiot btw.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: Access Denied suggests you're trying to move folders which are not held by the user but instead by other users.  Where are you running this from?  What directory?

Comment: Read `man find`, and `find . -type d -name '__pycache__" -ls`.

Comment: @Thomas Ward Thanks for your reply! I'm running this from the directory where the __pycache__ is. Full dir is /home/hoff/PINCE/libPINCE/ and there in lies pycache. I suppose I must login a root somehow?

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for your reply! I will read and see if I can understand ;)